# FOSOAuthServerBundle: OAuth2 Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant flow

Tags: doctrine-orm, oauth-2.0, symfony-2.1

I'm using **FOSOAuthServerBundle** in a Symfony2.1 project (using Doctrine) and I'd like to implement to use **Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant** flow.

I read the good article written by Burak Seydioglu "[Securing Syfmony2 REST services with FOSOAuthServerBundle](http://blog.logicexception.com/2012/04/securing-syfmony2-rest-service-wiith.html)" but he explains only "Authorization Code Grant" and "Implicit Grant" flows.

I read a comment that tried to explain it, but unsuccessfully.

I tried to create an URI with the requested parameter but I got some errors..

Thank you.